# Make error: install hqp (huge quadratic programming) on OS X

Tags: macos, gcc, makefile, quadratic

I am trying to install [hqp](http://hqp.sourceforge.net/installation.html) on OS X, but seems the `gcc` compiler is quite different.
When running `make`, I first come to an error like `malloc.h not found`, I wrap the `#include` header like:

```
#if !defined(__APPLE__)
#include <malloc.h>
#endif
```

In this way, the first problem is solved. 
But when I continue to run `make`, I got things like:

```
g++ -shared -o libhqp.so Hqp_Init.o Hqp.o sprcm.o Meschach.o spBKP.o matBKP.o bdBKP.o Hqp_impl.o Hqp_Program.o Hqp_Solver.o Hqp_Client.o Hqp_IpsFranke.o Hqp_IpsMehrotra.o Hqp_IpMatrix.o Hqp_IpSpBKP.o Hqp_IpRedSpBKP.o Hqp_IpLQDOCP.o t_mesch.o Hqp_IpSpSC.o meschext_hl.o Hqp_SqpSolver.o Hqp_SqpPowell.o Hqp_SqpSchittkowski.o Hqp_HL.o Hqp_HL_Gerschgorin.o Hqp_HL_DScale.o Hqp_HL_BFGS.o Hqp_HL_SparseBFGS.o Hqp_SqpProgram.o Hqp_Docp.o hqp_solve.o \
          ../meschach/*.o ../iftcl/*.o -L"/sw/lib" -Wl,-rpath,"/sw/lib" -ltclstub8.5
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2: ../meschach/*.o: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2: ../iftcl/*.o: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know what component is different this time? I tried reinstall the latest version of tcl, but it seems not to be the problem. Find it really hard to google a solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without actually testing the result, I got this to work using the following steps. I have to say that this set of makefiles does not work as it should, especially with regard to how the dependencies are set up.

First, edit `meschach/machine.h` and remove the `#include <malloc.h>`, or make it conditional like you did with the `__APPLE__` ifdef. The only reason why `malloc.h` is included seems to be for `malloc()` and `free()` and those get included via `stdlib.h` anyway.

Then edit `makedirs.in` and append `-I/usr/include/malloc` to `MES_INCDIR`, leaving you with `MES_INCDIR = -I.. -I/usr/include/malloc`.

With these two steps in place, doing `./configure` followed by `make` should already give you `libhqp.so` in the `lib` directory, which might be sufficient for you.

However, there is also an executable called `docp` in the directory `hqp_docp` which gets executed during the `make` process. It does not work because it can not find the shared libary `libhqp.so`. I resolved that by `cd`-ing into the `lib` directory and setting `export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD`. I am not sure whether running `docp` is an essential part of the process though.

Finally, the building of a library called `omu` breaks because the linker is not passed any reference to the required library `libhqp.so`. I did not figure out why this would work on other systems, and I do not know whether you need that `libomu` at all. I just did a quick fix by adding `-L../lib -lhqp` to the end of the linker-command in `omu/Makefile`. That is the command starting with `$(LD)`.

I hope I did not forget any of the steps I took, let me know if it still breaks for you somewhere.